# Map with list as value indexing

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Map that contains a List and I want to get a specific value.
Here is the map.

```dart
Map res ={65535: [198, 28, 231, 228, 87, 210, 255, 0, 57, 30, 14]} ;
```

I want to get to the value 57,
any help ?

Comment: can you include more details, as you are saying you like to get `57` from the list and from map you can get value using key. or just `myMap.values.toList()`. Can you clarify the use case what exactly you are trying to archive based on x condition?

Comment: Im using flutter_blue library and i want to get the value of heart rate "57" , here is a pice of the code                                                                                                       
    String getNiceManufacturerDataTemp(Map<int, List<int>> data) {
    if (data.isEmpty) {
      return 'N/A';
    }
    List<String> res = [];
    data.forEach((id, bytes) {
      res.add('${getNiceHexArraytmp(bytes)}');
    });
    return res.join(',');
  } i want to access to the list first then access to the desired value "57"

Comment: Do you like to get its key or just value 57 itself or the full list where 57 contains.

Comment: just the value "57" , but if u don't mind can you tell me how to get the key?

Comment: you can get  keys and find all the list and check where 57 contains return the key from there. How to get key where the x contains in map values, are you trying to do something like this?

Comment: i just need to access to the value 57 by using index

Comment: Ok then you are trying to get the  key and value index of `57`?

Comment: Have you tried `res[65535][8]`

Comment: I've got this error RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 65535

Comment: @Ghabrimouheb seems like  data have been changed, and I am not clear about the question, for null case you can do as Richard Heap commented `res[65535]?[8]`

Comment: yes it changed , because there is other ble devices that are sending data

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the snippet where element will find from values and provide key and element index.

```dart
  Map<int, List<int>> res = {
    65535: [198, 28, 231, 228, 87, 210, 255, 0, 57, 30, 14]
  };
  // while everything is int here
  final int findElement = 57;
  int? keyOf57;
  int? indexOf57;

  res.forEach((key, value) {
    if (value.contains(findElement)) {
      keyOf57 = key;
      indexOf57 = value.indexOf(findElement);
      return;
    }
  });
   /// also check if `indexOf57` is null or not
  print("key:$keyOf57  index:$indexOf57 value ${res[keyOf57]?[indexOf57??0]}");
```